# What ITG posts were deleted?

Tags: support, game-identification

I as a plebian can't search for deleted posts, but I assume someone else with superpowers can.  Can I get a list of these (links) so at the very least 10k users can reflect upon that quagmire?

Answer (score 1):

I think your best option is to download the [Stack Exchange Data Dump for December 2011](http://www.clearbits.net/torrents/1881-dec-2011) - before the great purge - and query the Gaming file for all the questions tagged [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game).

Comment: [Is there a nice browser to view a data dump?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111945/is-there-a-nice-browser-to-view-a-data-dump)

Comment: Don't think deleted stuff (at the time of dump) is in the data dump, is it?

Comment: @BenBrocka whoops, [you seem to be correct](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33568/data-dump-should-include-deleted-posts). Will fix the post.